# print string perl from desired position

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I have the following code and I want to see the last 3 folders from a directory

```
#read folders
opendir (DIR, "$path1") or die $!;
while ($file = readdir(DIR)) {
    next if ($file eq "." or $file eq "..");
    next unless (-d "$path1/$file");     
    if ($file =~ "@01-"){
        #print "$file\n";
        push @nr, $file;
        for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@nr)-7; $i++) {
             print "@nr[$i]\n"; #here is the problem
        }
    }
} 
closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Comment: What is it doing, what is it not doing ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `$file =~ "@01-"` ?

Comment: Please format your Perl code nicely - it is unreadable as it is, and that will hide the errors you from you just as much as it hides them from us. The problem may be here `if ($file =~ "@01-")`, which should be `if ($file =~ "\@01-")` to prevent Perl from trying to interpolate the non-existent array `@01`. If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` in place as you always should then you would have seen an error message telling you about this

Comment: also notice to get the element at position n of an array in perl you write `$array[n]` not `@array[n]`. You want the scalar at that position, so you use scalar context. As Borodin said, use strict; use warnings; and you will have some idea of what else is going wrong, probably (my $file), ...

Comment: I have a folder that is containing another 20 folders. in @01 i have a value used to sort the folders because I want to use only the folders that starts with V120 and after I get only the folders that I want I only want to see the last 3 of them. therefore  I use: for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@nr)-7; $i++) {
             print "@nr[$i]\n";
        }

Comment: @PopescuEmanuel: *"in @01 i have a value used to sort the folders"* do you mean the *array* `@01` or a *file* by that name? Normally identifiers start with a letter or an underscore, but without `use strict` in place you can get away with such monstrosities as `@01`. And it sounds like it should be a scalar anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your code and your question are dreadful, but what I *think* you're trying to do is this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ catfile /;
use List::Util qw/ max /;

my $path1 = '~/data';
my $prefix = 'V120';
my $tail = 3;

my @nr;

opendir my ($dh), $path1 or die $!;

while ( my $file = readdir $dh ) {

    next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';
    next unless $file =~ /^$prefix-/;
    next unless -d catfile($path1, $file);

    push @nr, $file;
}

for my $i ( max(@nr - $tail, 0) .. $#nr ) {
    print $nr[$i], "\n";
}
```

Comment: exactly what I want, Also for another Prefix I have to print the last folder, can you please help me with this for my $i ( max(@nr - $tail, 0) .. $#nr ) {
    print $nr[$i], "\n";

Comment: Okay, well you need to work on phrasing your questions better as it is far from clear what you're looking for. I realise that English is probably not your first language, but I'm sure you could have written more than *"I have the following code and I want to see the last 3 folders from a directory"* and answered the questions that people asked in the comments. To print just the *last* entry of `@nr` you could just set `$tail` to 1, or you could replace the `for` loop with just `print $nr[-1], "\n"`